# execve syscall returning EFAULT using 32bit call conventions on 64bit AMD

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm playing with manual syscalls in assembly. I was able to make it launch properly before, but after removing the nulls I'm not able to get the syscall to execute `/bin/date`. Here is the code I wrote in AT&T syntax.

```
.global main
main:
    jmp     two

one:
    # zero rax and rdx
    xor     %rax,%rax 
    mov     %rax,%rdx

    # save string location
    mov     (%rsp),%rbx

    # push argv array onto the stack
    add     $16, %rsp
    push    %rax
    push    %rbx
    # assign argv pointer
    mov     %rsp,%rcx

    # execve call
    mov     $0xb, %al 
    int     $0x80

    # exit on failure
    xor     %rax,%rax
    xor     %rbx,%rbx
    movb    $0x1,%al
    int     $0x80

two:
    # get address of the string
    call    one
    .string "/bin/date"
```

If I'm right, `%rbx` should point directly to the string which names the program to launch. `%rcx` should point to a null-terminated array of pointers representing the program's `argv`, and `%rdx` would point to the environment, so I've left it null here. And, of course, `%rax` holds the syscall number (`0x0b` in this case).

```
(gdb) info registers 
rax            0xb  11
rbx            0x4000a0 4194464
rcx            0x7fffffffe968   140737488349544
rdx            0x0  0

(gdb) x/s $rbx
0x4000a0:    "/bin/date"

(gdb) x/s *$rcx
0x4000a0:    "/bin/date"
```

Despite this, the syscall doesn't execute the program, and returns -14, which translates to `EFAULT` (segfault). I'm not sure what I'm overlooking, any help would be appreciated.

---

So, a perceptive reader might have noticed that the above code is using 32bit syscall conventions (using `%ebx`, `int $0x80` and friends) on a 64bit system. This was an error, as the 32bit convention is supported only to enable executing 32bit code. In code written for 64bit systems, syscalls use `%rdi`,`%rsi`, `%rdx`, `%r10`, `%r8` and `%r9` as well as the `syscall` instruction. Here is the corrected code for 64bit systems (nullfree):

```
.global main
main:
    jmp     two

one:
    # zero rax and rdx
    xor     %rax,%rax 
    mov     %rax,%rdx

    # save string location, note that %rdi is used instead of %rbx
    pop     %rdi

    # push argv array onto the stack
    add     $16, %rsp
    push    %rax
    push    %rdi
    # assign argv pointer, using %rsi instead of %rcx
    mov     %rsp,%rsi

    # execve call, note that the syscall number is different than in 32bit
    mov     $0x3b, %al 
    syscall

two:
    # get address of the string
    call    one
    .string "/bin/date"
```

However, the 32bit syscall convention *is* supported on 64bit systems (hence 32bit executables can be run), and I have also successfully `execve`d other commands using the 32bit call convention on this system. In fact, a large majority of the "shellcode" I examined for x86_64 systems used the 32bit conventions. So, my question still stands: **why didn't the 32bit calling conventions work in the above code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why didn't the 32bit calling conventions work in the above code?

You answered your own question:

> The 32bit convention is supported only to enable executing 32bit code.

It's only accidental that you can invoke it from 64 bit code too, the kernel does not check. It expects the call to originate in 32 bit code, and zero extends the 32 bit registers with the arguments to 64 bit since the interface only uses 32 bit registers. This is done in [ia32entry.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/ia32/ia32entry.S?id=14f6e9532dda399a7b789f744dc045f8865a9e42#n429) (remember that 32 bit operations in 64 bit mode clear the top 32 bits of registers automatically):

```
/*
 * Emulated IA32 system calls via int 0x80.
 *
 * Arguments:
 * eax  system call number
 * ebx  arg1
 * ecx  arg2
 * edx  arg3
 * esi  arg4
 * edi  arg5
 * ebp  arg6    (note: not saved in the stack frame, should not be touched)
 *
 * Notes:
 * Uses the same stack frame as the x86-64 version.
 * All registers except eax must be saved (but ptrace may violate that).
 * Arguments are zero extended. For system calls that want sign extension and
 * take long arguments a wrapper is needed. Most calls can just be called
 * directly.
 * Assumes it is only called from user space and entered with interrupts off.
 */
[...]    
ia32_do_call:
    /* 32bit syscall -> 64bit C ABI argument conversion */
    movl %edi,%r8d  /* arg5 */
    movl %ebp,%r9d  /* arg6 */
    xchg %ecx,%esi  /* rsi:arg2, rcx:arg4 */
    movl %ebx,%edi  /* arg1 */
    movl %edx,%edx  /* arg3 (zero extension) */
    call *ia32_sys_call_table(,%rax,8) # xxx: rip relative
```

As such, you can't use it to pass arguments that don't fit into 32 bits. Notice that your `rcx` value is `0x7fffffffe968` which will thus be truncated to `0xffffe968` and ultimately cause the `EFAULT`.

`rcx` was of course set from `rsp`, and typical 64 bit address space has the stack growing downwards from the top of the positive half of the address space and that is outside of the 32 bit range. To prove this, you can switch to a stack located in low memory. The following code works fine:

```
.lcomm stack, 4096
.global main
main:
    movl    $stack, %esp
    jmp     two

one:
    # zero rax and rdx
    xor     %rax,%rax
    mov     %rax,%rdx

    # save string location
    mov     (%rsp),%rbx

    # push argv array onto the stack
    add     $16, %rsp
    push    %rax
    push    %rbx
    # assign argv pointer
    mov     %rsp,%rcx

    # execve call
    mov     $0xb, %al
    int     $0x80

    # exit on failure
    xor     %rax,%rax
    xor     %rbx,%rbx
    movb    $0x1,%al
    int     $0x80

two:
    # get address of the string
    call    one
    .string "/bin/date"
```

Answer (score 2):

The execve() call has prototype

```
int execve(const char *filename,
           char *const argv[],
           char *const envp[]);
```

Note that `NULL` pointers are not usually passed, but if the `envp[]` array is to be empty, you should pass a pointer to a NULL which serves as the end of environment variables.  Likewise, `argv[]` cannot be a NULL pointer.  It must contain, at a minimum, `argv[0]` which is the program name.  It is usually sufficient to place `filename` as the first element.  To be perfectly conforming to what the shell does, strip the path and pass only the last component as argv[0] (`date` in your example).

The equivalent C code for your example is:

```
char *filename = "/bin/date";
char *argv [2] = {filename, NULL};
char *envp [1] = {NULL};

execve (filename, argv, envp);
```

Maybe I'm missing it, but it looks like you are doing the equivalent of (both 32 and 64 bit)

```
char *filename = "/bin/date";

execve (filename, NULL);   // note missing third parameter, and malformed argv[]
```

I don't understand your stack manipulation.  It should be sufficient to push, push, push, syscall.  I am confused why you directly manipulate the stack pointer.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `argv` (or `rcx` in the 32bit code) points to an array of `char*` (note the gdb output after the code). I manipulate the stack pointer to keep from clobbering the `/bin/date` string (which is pointed to by `rsp` after the `jmp`/`call` trickery). I am almost certainly overlooking something though; I'll look over it more in the morning.

Comment: @bkconrad:  good enough.  I am tired as well and will look more carefully at it in 9 hours.